# Django Host name for an ip address

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have an ip address say x.x.x.x:8080 ,how can i mask this ip address and run as labview.net:8080 so that ip address cannot be exposed to the users.Can any one please explain the steps to be followed? (i'm using windows machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you just want to use a domain for your server?
For that you should first config your dns nameservers in your server , it has many ways like [this tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-and-configure-dns-server-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), and after that you should use your dns config in your domain control panel.
In short hands you can pass ip address to your domain nameservers and it should works properly.
This solution is not related to django or what is your server language.